# Product page says "out of stock" even though SKU at 50

Tags: magento

I've created a catalog with about 10 products and I've made sure each of them have a SKU of at least 50.

Yet, when I go to an individual product's page, it tells me that the product is out of stock - which makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: +1, Refresh your browser and also clear its cache

Comment: Maybe that is what it's coded to do but we will never know.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the quick response but I'm still getting a "out of stock" message: http://i.imgur.com/fz4Va.png -- the SKU is the STOCK option right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SKU is the unique identifier for a product, not the quantity of inventory of that item in stock.  On a typical retail product, the SKU is the number coded into the product's bar code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out man. I've adjusted the product quantity now but I still cannot see any products on the home page.